# What kind of federation was postulated by the six point movement?

Tags: federalism

- [Six point movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_point_movement#The_six_points)

If

1. Federal government is only responsible for defence and foreign affairs
2. federating members keep different currencies
3. federating members keep different accounts for export income
4. federating members keep their own military/paramilitary force
5. The power of taxation and revenue collection should be vested in the federating units, and the federal center would have no such power. The federation would be entitled to a share of the state taxes to meet its expenditures.

What kind of federation is it?

Can you give me an example of a federation in the history of mankind where at least three of the above points existed?

Comment: point 2 is pretty rare but non non-existent, in case of large physical separation "France not only manages the euro, but its overseas territories in the Pacific such as French Polynesia, New Caledonia, and Wallis and Fortuna use the Franco CFP." I'm not sure if the latter is pegged to the Euro or what, nowadays. Can find the details on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFP_franc

Comment: Similarly there's some cornucopia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_currencies although most seem pegged to the Sterling.

Comment: Probably most of the ill-fated Arab unions met most those points though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_of_Arab_Republics_(1972) ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Federation ;  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_of_Arab_Republics ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Arab_States ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Arab_Republic etc.

Comment: The United Nations fits the last four points pretty well, and the first point if you consider their peacekeeping missions as defensive. However, I don't know if the UN has ever really been called a 'federation', so would you consider something as loose as the UN as an answer?

Comment: @Giter The United Nations also fits the first point well when you consider which actors the UN has *foreign* as opposed to *domestic* relations with. If anything, peacekeeping missions give the UN more power than the proposed federation, because internal conflicts might not fall under the purview of "defence and foreign affairs" as outlined by the Six point movement (I suspect they would have wanted the federal army to stay out of a conflict between East and West Pakistan).